# show array data in react table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I have an both an array, and the state array.

```
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState([]);
  let ure = [{}]
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/api/listUre")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
        //setFormData(res.data);
       ure.push({
             class_id: res.data.class_id
         })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
      });
  }, []);
```

once I do that, I now want to access the `class_id` from within a table:

```
{ure.length > 0 &&
            ure.map((obj, index) => {

       
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>
              {obj.class_id}
            </td>
            <td>
              {obj.class_id}
            </td>
            <td>
               My Name
            </td>
          </tr>
         })}
      {ure.length === 0 && "No Data Found"}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it is not outputting anything to the page. and i know that the `ure` array has data in it because it isn't outputting `"No Data Found"` to the screen, so it should be working. can anyone help me out?

Comment: You don't have an `output` property in your object. Either `ure.map(({ class_id }, index) => {...}` and then `<td>{class_id}</td>` _or_ `ure.map((obj, index) => {...}` and then `<td>{obj.class_id}</td>`.

Comment: @Andy appreciate the reply. I've updated my question to show what I did based on your answer, however, nothing is still being outputted to the screen. Any chance I missed something?

Comment: Are you using state to store this data?

Comment: @Andy no I am storing in just a plain array. Although when I use state, the same thing happens. I just tried it.

Comment: And where is `res.data` coming from? It looks like the result of an axios request (which should probably be in a `useEffect` that stores the data in state...), Rough guess :)

Comment: @Andy yessir! I've just updated my question to show that as well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245306/discussion-between-devdude19289-and-andy).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `ure` to be a piece of state, otherwise your `ure` array will keep getting reevaluated each time your component re-renders.

So, the first step would be to:

```
const [ure, setUre] = useState([]);
```

Then for changing `ure`, just do something like:

```
setUre(currUre => {
  return currUre.concat([{ foo: bar }]);
})
```

Then, to iterate over it, you shouldn't need to check the `length > 0`, just the `map()` will do the trick.

The reason why you're seeing that outcome (no table but no empty array) is because you're initializing `let ure = [{}]`, which is an array of size 1 with an empty object in it.